# Performance of thenComparing vs thenComparingInt - which to use?

Tags: sorting, java-8, comparator

I have a question, if I'm comparing ints, is there a performance difference in calling thenComparingInt(My::intMethod) vs thenComparing(My::intMethod), in other words, if I'm comparing differemt types, both reference and primitive, e.g. String, int, etc. Part of me just wants to say comparing().thenComparing().thenComparing() etc, but should I do comparing.thenComparing().thenComparingInt() if the 3rd call was comparing an int or Integer value?

I am assuming that comparing() and thenComparing() use the compareTo method to compare any given type behind the scenes or possibly for ints, the Integer.compare? I'm also assuming the answer to my original question may involve performance in that thenComparingInt would know an int is being passed in, whereas, thenComparing would have to autobox int to Integer then maybe cast to Object?

Also, another question whilst I think of it - is there a way of chaining method references, e.g. Song::getArtist::length where getArtist returns a string? Reason is I wanted to do something like this:

```
songlist.sort(
            Comparator.comparing((Song s) -> s.getArtist().length()));


    songlist.sort(
            Comparator.comparing(Song::getArtist, 
                    Comparator.comparingInt(String::length)));


    songlist.sort(
            Comparator.comparing(Song::getArtist, String::length));
```

Of the 3 examples, the top two compile but the bottom seems to throw a compilation error in Eclipse, I would have thought the 2nd argument of String::length was valid? But maybe not as it's expecting a Comparator not a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question 1

I would think `thenComparingInt(My::intMethod)`  might be better since it should avoid boxing, but you would have to try out both versions to see if it really makes a difference.

Question 2

```
songlist.sort(
        Comparator.comparing(Song::getArtist, String::length));
```

Is invalid because the 2nd parameter should be a `Comparator` not a method that returns int.

Comment: My guess is that very little performance will be gained with the primitive specialization. Escape analysis won't have much problem detecting that the autoboxed int is confined to the comparison method's scope, and then the `Integer.compareTo` method can be inlined to produce almost the same result as without autoboxing. So benchmarking is a must to find the actual difference.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik If only that were so.  Lots of actual measurement was done before we committed to including primitive stream specializations.  That said, performance is rarely the most important requirement; if you've got six elements in your collection, sorting it is probably fast enough no matter how much boxing you do, and fast enough is fast enough.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Indeed, I've compared `Arrays.sort(integerArray, comparing(Integer::intValue));` against `Arrays.sort(integerArray, comparingInt(Integer::intValue));` and the performance ratio was 3.5 to 1 in favor of the primitive specialization, when using integers outside of the integer cache range; when within the cache range (0..127), performance of the boxed variant was better (2 to 1). This indicates that Escape Analysis didn't allow stack allocation, based my previous observation that EA'd Integers perform *better* than when looked up from the cache.

Comment: @BrianGoetz ...following up on the above finding, I also tested `Arrays.sort(integerArray, comparing(i->new Integer(i.intValue())));`---and, lo and behold, the ratio was just 1.5 to 1 in this case. I overlooked that `Integer.valueOf` (in other words, autoboxed code) cannot be EA'd due to the code path involving cache lookup. So my prediction does hold after all: with EA in effect, the difference becomes quite small.

Comment: (rereading the above, I see room for confusion where I say "performance of the boxed variant was better"; what I intended was "performance of the boxed variant *improved*---from 3.5:1 in favor of the primitive variant to 2:1)

Comment: By now, I'm not really sure what your argument _is_, but it seems to be that "primitive streams were not necessary, because EA makes the boxing pain go away" -- which is totally wrong.  EA works well in some situations, and terribly in others; depending on the locality of your operations, these issues may dominate the boxing/unboxing costs, making these look cheaper than they are.  Also, are you comparing raw sequential performance or parallel speedup?  Again, depending what you measure, you can see very different results.  Bottom line: I wish that EA worked as reliably as you think it does.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I agree with whatever Brian Goetz says considering he's one of the Java 8 authors.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I know you're a little touchy about this subject and have probably got a lot of flak by now, but I was just entertaining my enthusiasm about  JVM performance :) I intuited that, in this *particular* case, EA should work. And I was wrong, but not completely so: it did work, but only when I used an explicit `Integer` constructor---which can BTW be interpreted as a hint on how to make an important improvement in the performance of boxing. EA should be attempted without considering the autoboxing technique, and constructor used instead of factory if EA succeeds.

Comment: @dkatzel Brian is more than just one of the authors---he's holding the position of the chief Java language architect :)